# prependTo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting data in `cometD` but when i use `prependTo` it doesn't show any thing. when i use `prepend` then it shows. but i want to use `prependTo`. and for some reason it is not working. below is my code.

```
function message() {
   this.messageDialog = $('<div id="messageDialog"></div>');
   this.messageDiv = $('<div id="messageDiv"></div>');  
   this.show = function() {     
        this.messageDialog.dialog({
            title : 'Message Board',
            width : 800,
            minHeight : 150,    
            position: 'bottom',
            close : function(ev, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.messageDiv.appendTo(this.messageDialog);
    }
}

dojox.cometd.subscribe('/service/order', function(message) {                
    var getString = message.data.test;          
    //$(getString+"<br/>").prependTo("#messageDiv");
    $(message.data.test+"<br/>").prependTo("#messageDiv");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is looking for a selector that doesn't exists. Try the below code:

```
$("#messageDiv").html(message.data.test+"<br/>");
```

Or try wrapping your string in another tag like below:

```
$('<p>'+message.data.test+'<br/></p>').prependTo("#messageDiv");
```

Comment: Sandeep the issue is solved, but basically why i have used prependTo becasue the string is coming after the DOM is created thats why i didn't use prepend, there was the reason why i move to prependTo and that reason is again occuring. the string is coming now but next when i again fetch the data, duplicate contents occurs. what is this reason.

Comment: Sorry, but where does the duplicate contents occur? According to your code, you are trying to **add** the content instead of **replacing** it. Is that the what you are referring to?

Comment: Sandeep, duplicate content occurs in the div. for e.g first time meesage recieve A and it prepended to a div, next time when message recieve a string B it is prepended to a Div, but two times(duplicate). so in a Div it shows A B B instead of A B.